# How can I lock a record in Hibernate 4.x

Tags: hibernate

My application uses Hibernate 4.x, Java, and Spring MVC.

Asssume that 2 users attempt to update a record at the same time. I want to lock the record to the first user's session until their edits are completed and notify the second user.

Previously, it looked like you could use `get(Classname.class, serialize, LockOption)`, but now it looks like it is deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[LockMode](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/LockMode.html) was replaced with [LockOptions](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/LockOptions.html) in 4.x. The get method (and other similar methods) for doing explicit pessimistic locking now have an overloaded method taking a LockOptions parameter which is not deprecated.

- [Session.get(String, Serializable, org.hibernate.LockOptions)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#get%28java.lang.String,%20java.io.Serializable,%20org.hibernate.LockOptions%29)

Comment: thank you for suggestion but it still not be locked, it still be updated by the sendcond user

Comment: You need to edit your question then, or create a new question, specifying exactly what you have tried, ideally with code. For instance, what lock option are using? How have you determined that the record is not locked? How do you demarcate your transaction (begin/commit) boundaries? (A lock at this level generally only makes sense if the record is held "open" in #1 transaction while an attempt is made to update in #2 transaction.)

Comment: In my apllication, I creat 2 class and they have main() funtion. The first class include below:
LockRecord p = (LockRecord)session.get(LockRecord.class, 2, LockOptions.UPGRADE);

Comment: In my apllication, I creat 2 class and they have main() funtion. The first class includes below code:
LockRecord p = (LockRecord)session.get(LockRecord.class, 2, LockOptions.UPGRADE);
In the second class includes :
Query query = session.createQuery("from LockRecord c where c.id =2");
        List lstResult = query.list();
        LockRecord p = (LockRecord)lstResult.get(0);
  p.setName("Phong");
  session.saveOrUpdate(p);
I debug first class and run second class, the result the record was still be updated in the second class

Comment: You have still not provided enough information. Consider posting the code of both classes, and indicate exactly which line you are setting your breakpoint at in the first class.  Also indicate what database you are using. You should try logging the SQL hibernate is generating. Also might try doing an explicit lock instead of trying to lock with the get operation. i.e. `session.get(LockRecord.class, 2); session.buildLockRequest().setLockMode(LockOptions.UPGRADE).setTimeOut(60000).lock(p);`

Comment: Hi thanks my friend. I have locked a record. But i see a problems belows:
When class1 run and the record was locked but orrcurs a exception when i updated the record then the record was not released. How can I release this record ?